# Why do I get the error "cannot unpack non-iterable bool object" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I get the error "cannot unpack non-iterable bool object" as I try to get user input from a form in django which in this case is an email.

```
def send_email(request):
      recepient_list=[]
      if request.method == "POST":
            
            email = request.POST['pwd_email']
            print(email)
            if User.objects.filter(email == email).exists:
                  recepient_list.append(email)
                  send_mail("PASSWORD RESET", f"Your password reset key is {random_no} \n Do not share this key with anyone", "eliaakjtrnq@gmail.com",recepient_list,fail_silently=False,)
                  recepient_list.clear()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here, the main one is `.filter(email == email)`. This will check if the string is equal to itself, and therefore always `True`, you thus use `.filter(True)`, and Django can of course not do much with the `bool`.

You should filter with:

```
def send_email(request):
    recepient_list = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['pwd_email']
        print(email)
        #                      ***call*** .exists() 🖟
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            recepient_list.append(email)
            send_mail(
                'PASSWORD RESET',
                f"Your password resetkey is {random_no} \n Do not share this key with anyone",
                'eliaakjtrnq@gmail.com',
                recepient_list,
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            recepient_list.clear()
```

Comment: thanks for the correction on  'email==email'

Answer (score 2):

The line that I believe is giving you some trouble is:

```py
if User.objects.filter(email == email).exists:
```

There are two issues that I see:

1. You should being using an assignment "=" rather than a check for equality "=="
2. `exists()` is a method, not an attribute so you need to include the "()"

Try changing that line to:

```py
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
```

and see if your error still persists.

Comment: OOH thank you very much id just not recognised it .  This worked out